# Problem when using several functions in the mouseover event handler

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with d3v5 and currently trying to make a node of a force-directed graph:

1. fade out the nodes which are not directly connected to the 'mouse-over'ed' node
2. enlarge the node at hand

So far I have managed the former but I can not manage for any function to get triggered alongside the `fade()` function. Consider:

```
 var node = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", function (d) {
      return 1.5 * Math.sqrt(d.weight);
    })
    .attr("fill", function (d) {
      return "red";
    })
    .call(
      d3
        .drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended)
    )
    .on("mouseover", fade(0.2))
    .on("mouseout", fade(1));
```

and the 'fade' function:

```
  function fade(opacity) {
    return function (d) {
      // check all other nodes to see if they're connected
      // to this one. if so, keep the opacity at 1, otherwise
      // fade
      node.style("stroke-opacity", function (o) {
        thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
        return thisOpacity;
      });
      node.style("fill-opacity", function (o) {
        thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
        return thisOpacity;
      });
      // also style link accordingly
      link.style("stroke-opacity", function (o) {
        return o.source.name === d.name || o.target.name === d.name
          ? 1
          : opacity;
      });
      text.style("fill-opacity", function (o) {
        thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
        return thisOpacity;
      });
    };
  }
```

So far everything works as it's supposed to. However as I started looking around to have another function execute on mouseover (and mouseout), I attempted the conventional method, as follows:

```
  var node = svg
    //...
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
      console.log("make node bigger")
      fade(0.2);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function (d) {
      console.log("make node smaller")
      fade(1);
    });
```

The two console messages are outputted, but the `fade()` function does not execute. I tried putting `return fade(...);` but to no avail.

I'd appreciate any insight on why this is happening. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do...

```
.on("mouseover", fade(0.2))
```

... you're calling `fade` immediately, and returning its return value, which is itself a function:

```
return function (d) { //etc...
```

That `d` parameter you see correspond to the first argument passed by the `selection.on()` method. At the end all you have is an idiomatic D3 listener, which is an anonymous function accepting the datum as the first argument.

However, now that you're doing this...

```
.on("mouseover", function (d) {
    console.log("make node bigger")
    fade(0.2);
})
```

... you have to refactor the `fade` function, because the datum is not being passed as an argument anymore. The easiest way is just passing the datum as an argument:

```
.on("mouseover", function (d) {
    console.log("make node bigger")
    fade(d, 0.2);
    //   ^---- datum here
})
```

And then, in `fade`, add a parameter for the datum and remove the `return function(d)` part:

```
function fade(d, opacity) {
    //datum---^
    node.style("stroke-opacity", function (o) {
        thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
        return thisOpacity;
    });
    //etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `fade()`, replace:

```js
node.style("stroke-opacity", function (o) {
   thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
   return thisOpacity;
});
```

with:

```js
node.style("opacity", function (o) {
   thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
   return thisOpacity;
});
```

Comment: This did not solve the issue at hand. `.on("mouseover", function (d) {
      fade(0.2);
    })` still does not work with that change.